# Location in mongoose, mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

Whenever I try to store a location in my mongodb it doesn't show, so I guess I'm doing something wrong.
I can't find any documentation on how to store a location in mongoose so I'm just gonna ask it here.

I first create my model:

```
var eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    name : String,
    creator : String,
    location : { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere'},

});
```

Then I try to add it to my database:

```
var newevent = new event({ 
        name: name,
        creator: tokenUser, 
        location : { type: "Point", coordinates: [longitude, latitude] },
});
```

When I look in my database everything is stored except the location ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed it myself.

I did this in my model:

```
loc :  { type: {type:String}, coordinates: [Number]},
```

Underneath I made it a 2dsphere index.

```
eventSchema.index({loc: '2dsphere'});
```

And to add data to it:

```
loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ longitude, latitude ] },
```

Comment: How the entry will comes in your collection for the property `loc` ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your comment is correct (maybe), but the syntax for the index schemetype

here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-index

It only accepts Object, Boolean, String

The correct syntax should be I think

```
var eventSchema = new Schema({ 
        location: { type: [Number], index: { type: '2dsphere', sparse: true}}
)
```

based on the example in the docs.

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html
Look for '2dsphere'

My model is right I think, I just don't know how to add the location to it.

Comment: Can you create a doc with a 2dsphere index on your Mongo DB manually? (via the command line)

Answer (score 2):

This way i find it simpler.

```
const GeoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: "Point",
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [Number], //the type is an array of numbers
    index: "2dsphere"
  }
})

const EventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  creator: String,
  location: GeoSchema
})
```

And when entering data

```
Event({
      name,
      creator,
      location: { type: "point", coordinates: [longitude, latitude] }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Citing from the mongoose documentation for [defining coordinates in schema,](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/geojson.html) I'd like to make a tiny addition to @Laurenswuyts' answer for the 'type' property.

```
const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String, // Don't do `{ location: { type: String } }`
      enum: ['Point'], // 'location.type' must be 'Point'
      required: true
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true
    }
  }
});
```

Instead of leaving the 'type' property of 'location' open-ended with 'type: String', defining it with a single option enum 'Point' and setting 'required' to 'true' makes the code more robust. Then you would create index and add data the same way @Laurenswuyts did.