# Save location in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I'm trying to save coordinates in my `2dsphere` model.

This is my model:

```
var userSchema   = new Schema({
  email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    ...
    loc: {
      type: {
          type: "String",
          required: true,
          enum: ['Point', 'LineString', 'Polygon'],
          default: 'Point'
      },
      coordinates: [Number]
    }

});
userSchema.index({'loc': '2dsphere'});
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User
```

My query to save new data is formated as follow:

```
email:eu@vc.com
password:t12345
name:Igor
type:true
loc:{
coordinates: [-43.306174, -22.844279]
}
```

And this is the error that I recieve:

```
{
    "code": 16804,
    "index": 0,
    "errmsg": "location object expected, location array not in correct format",
    "op": {
        "email": "eu@vc.com",
        "password": "t12345",
        "name": "Igor",
        "_id": "5a311c016d15fc235895bef3",
        "created_at": "2017-12-13T12:24:33.493Z",
        "loc": {
            "coordinates": [],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "type": true,
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218389/location-in-mongoose-mongodb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Location in mongoose, mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218389/location-in-mongoose-mongodb)

Comment: @maxpaj @Neodan trying the way in the post run in this error: `"errmsg": "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5a31c82b3a84041e1c42ee78'), email: \"eu@vc.com\", password: \"tbi729\", name: \"Igor\", created_at: new Date(1513211947354), loc: { coordinates: [] }, type: true, __v: 0 }  unknown GeoJSON type: { coordinates: [] }",`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have both 2d  and 2dsphere index on collection.

The [error](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/index/expression_keys_private.cpp#L282) below indicates you have a 2d index.

```
"errmsg": "location object expected, location array not in correct format",
```

So when you try to save spherical coordinates (`{"loc": {"coordinates": [23, 25],"type": "Point"}`) you get the error when mongodb builds the index.

The error ([first part](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/index/expression_keys_private.cpp#L138) & [second part](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/geo/geoparser.cpp#L698)) below indicates you have a 2d sphere index.

```
"errmsg": "Can't extract geo keys: {...loc: { coordinates: [23, 25] }} unknown GeoJSON type
```

So when you change to `{"loc": {"coordinates": [23, 25] }}`,  2d sphere index fails to build.

You can verify the indexes. `db.users.getIndexes()`

Drop the 2d index (still there for  backward compatibility). 2d sphere index supports both legacy coordinates (eg `{"loc":[23, 25]}`) and geo coordinates.

```
db.users.dropIndex( "loc_2d" )
```

This should work when 2d sphere index rebuilds index for collection.

Drop the collection and start over if above solution doesn't work.

```
db.users.drop()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. All your documents' ***loc*** property must follow **geoJSON** format. I see some documents are with a empty array of ***coordinates*** in ***loc*** property which is wrong.

   ```
   "loc": {  
       "coordinates": [],  //should NOT be an empty array, should be with 2 number items such as [ -43.306174, -22.844279]
       "type": "Point"  
   },
   ```
2. Make sure that some wrong-format documents are cleared up. Keep all documents are following valid formats.