# Cannot create Mongoose Object with location field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geolocation, mongoose-schema

Using Mongoose, I can't insert location data into the database :

```
Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?
```

It seems that the POST request is OK (LOG A) : It has a location ('loc') field, but the object I create from this POST request is missing the 'loc' field data :

Here is my Schema :

**models/Article.js**

```
var ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    slug: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true},
    title: String,
    description: String,
    body: String,
    loc :  { type: {type:String}, coordinates: [Number]},
    favoritesCount: {type: Number, default: 0},
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
    tagList: [{ type: String }],
    author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
}, {timestamps: true});

ArticleSchema.index({loc: '2dsphere'});
```

**routes/Article.js**

```
router.post('/', auth.required, function(req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.payload.id).then(function(user){
      if (!user) { return res.sendStatus(401); }

      var article = new Article(req.body.article);

      // LOG A
      console.log(req.body.article);

      // LOG B
      console.log(article);

      article.author = user;

      return article.save().then(function(){
         return res.json({article: article.toJSONFor(user)});
      });
      ...
```

And here are the output :

LOG A : req.body.article

```
{ title: 'article title',
  description: 'about section',
  body: 'Article body',
  tagList: [],
  loc: '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[38.9173025,-77.220978]}' 
}
```

LOG B : article created with *var article = new Article(req.body.article);*

```
{ loc: { coordinates: [] },
  favoritesCount: 0,
  comments: [],
  tagList: [],
  _id: 5a384f502c9912312c6dd89d,
  body: 'Article body',
  description: 'about section',
  title: 'article title' 
}
```

My problem, is that the loc field began **"{ coordinates: [] }"** instead of **{"type":"Point","coordinates":[38.9173025,-77.220978]}** when creating the objet "Article".

Why is that the location data isn't in the Object ?

I've been looking a this question first : [Location in mongoose, mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218389/location-in-mongoose-mongodb)

Comment: Can`t cast it because it is string (note the single quotes around the value for loc  variable in  Log A output ) whereas mongoose expects object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Veeram : The problem was my POST request : The location was sent as string instead of an object :

In my Angular front-end :

**article.model.ts BEFORE**

```
export class Article {
  ....
  loc: string
  ....
}
```

**article.model.ts AFTER**

```
class Location {
  constructor(
    public type: string,
    public coordinates: Array<number> = []
  ){}
}

export class Article {
  ....
  loc: Location
  ....
}
```